# Custom UIButton inside UIBarButtonItem inside UIToolbar. TouchDown event not called on first button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have an empty UIToolbar and in it I programmatically create two UIBarButtonItems which contain UIButton subviews. These UIButtons are made up of a UILabel:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addSubview:ackButtonLabel];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ackButtonLabel.frame.size.width, ackButtonLabel.frame.size.height)];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressAck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapDownCancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

[newItems addObject:myButton];
```

I then add a second button with exactly the same code, referencing a different but identically created label and add them all to the toolbar.

When this displays it looks like this

[image]

Which is what I want. However when I go to tap the button and hold my finger down in the same place... the left hand button will not trigger the TouchDown event, but the right hand button will. The event does get triggered when the finger is moved ever so slightly, but not when it is held stationary. In the simulator the behaviour does not occur and a click and hold on either button works fine to trigger the event. If I swap the labels round, it only occurs on the left hand one.

Any ideas? Apple bug?

Comment: If anyone else feels this has been happening to them, rather than offer a solution I can at least make you feel less bad about it. In the eBay iOS app, the Buy Now / Watch buttons at the bottom of each item behave in the same way, the left button does not highlight on press, only on press & move, but the right button does.